# How to convert an ArrayList of String arrays into a 2D string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<String[]> array_list`
I want to convert it into a 2D String array say result
such that first string array in array_list is in `result[0]`.
Also I want to have first string in result to be equal to string `equal`.
i.e.
If first array in array_list has `["A","B","C"]`
and my string `equal` is `"D"` my `result[0]` should be `["D","A","B","C"]`

I tried:

```
ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
// I'm getting value of result from a function
String[][] array = new String[result.size()][]; 
int j =0;
for (String[] arrs : result)
{
    System.out.println(j);
    String arr = n;//I have taken n as parameter for the function
    array[j][0] = arr;
    int i =1;
    for(String o : arrs)
    {
        array[j][i] = o;
        i++;
    }
    j++;
}
```

but this gives `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: At what line is the nullpointerexception thrown?

Answer (score 3):

`array[j]` is never initialized. You have to first assign a `String[]` instance to `array[j]` before using it.

Add the following line at the beginning of your outer for-loop (before `array[j][0] = arr`):

```
array[j] = new String[arrs.length + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative (to your question in the title).

My initial thought was to do the following;

`String[][] array = (String[][]) result.toArray()`

But it turns out to give a nasty `ClassCastException` telling we can't cast an `Object` array to a `String` array.

So, this is where the `Arrays` class (`java.util.Arrays`) comes in handy.

`String[][] array = Arrays.copyOf(result.toArray(), result.toArray().length, String[][].class);`

Or fancy Java 8;

`String[][] array = Arrays.stream(result.toArray()).toArray(String[][]::new);`